# Prove that the set is dense in $C^{0}([0,1];\mathbb{C})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose now I have a subset $S \subset C^{0}([0,1];\mathbb{C})$. And the set $S$ satisfies a certain degree of density, that is to say, for any $\delta > 0$, if we form a new set $S_{\delta}$ by restricting all elements of the set $S$ within the interval $[\delta,1-\delta]$, this set $S_{\delta}$ is dense in $C^{0}([\delta,1-\delta];\mathbb{C})$.

The question is: can we infer from this that $S$ is dense in $C^{0}([0,1];\mathbb{C})$?

If not, what additional condition are needed it to hold ?

Comment: Did you mean that $S_\delta$ is dense in $C^0([\delta,1-\delta])$ (without compact support)? If so, then the answer is yes

Comment: @Eric I apologize for the misunderstanding. Here,the symbol $C_{\mathbb{C}}^{0}([0,1])$ refer to continuous functions from the closed interval $[0,1]$ to the complex filed $\mathbb{C}$. Additionally ,could you provide a proof?

Comment: ohhh, now i get it. Then i believe it is true, since you can approximate any function very well on $[\delta,1-\delta]$ by the density, and the estimate can't go too wrong on the remaining 2 intervals by uniform continuity (compact domain + continuous).

Comment: If we're using the usual $L^\infty$ topology for continuous functions, then I don't think it's true. If $S$ is the set of continuous functions $f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ for example, then $S_\delta$ is dense in $C^0([\delta, 1-\delta],\mathbb{C})$, but $S$ can never approach any continuous function $g$ such that $g(0)\neq0$ or $g(1)\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot derive that $S$ is dense if $S_\delta$ is dense for all $\delta > 0$. For simplicity, I will write $C^0 =C^0([0,1], \mathbb{C})$ and $C^0_\delta=C^0([\delta,1-\delta], \mathbb{C})$.

Consider the set $S := \{ f \in C^0 \mid  f(0) = 0 \}$, which is clearly not dense in $C^0$. However, for any $\delta > 0$ and $\hat{f} \in C^0_\delta$, we can define the functon $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in [0,\delta/2] \\
\frac{2 \hat{f}(\delta)}{\delta} ( x - \delta/2) & x \in[\delta/2,\delta] \\
\hat{f}(x) & x \in[\delta , 1 - \delta] \\
\hat{f}(1-\delta) & x \in [1-\delta, 1] \end{cases}$$

By construction, we have $f|_{[\delta,1-\delta]} = \hat{f}$, $f(0) = 0$, and $f$ is continuous. Thus $f \in S$, and therefore $S_\delta = C^0_\delta$.

Hence, there exists a set $S$ such that $S_\delta$ is dense in $C^0_\delta$ for all $\delta > 0$, but $S$ is not dense in $C^0$.

My initial guess for the extra constraint was to assume that $\{ (f(0),f(1)) \mid f \in S\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}^2$, but this is not enough to show that $S$ is dense in $C^0$. To see this, consider the set
$$S = \{f \in C^0 \mid f(0) = 0 \text{ or } f \text{ is a line} \}.$$
Then by the reasoning above, $S_\delta$ is dense in $C^0_\delta$, but the function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - 2x & x \le 1/2 \\ 2x -1 & x \ge 1/2 \end{cases}$$
still cannot be approximated in $S$.

So I assume the extra constraint would be something like $S^{a,b} = \{ f \in S \mid f(0) = a, f(1) = b \}$ should also satisfy that $S^{a,b}_\delta$ is dense in $C^0_\delta$ for all $(a,b)$ in a dense subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$, but I do not have proof that this is sufficient to show that $S$ is dense in $C^0$.

**EDIT:**

My proposed extra constraint is still not enough. So see this, consider the set
$$S = \{ f \in C^0 \mid \exists \varepsilon_f \text{ such that $f$ is a line between $f(0)$ and $0$ on $[0,\varepsilon_f].$}\}.$$

Then for any $(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2$, $\delta > 0$, and $\hat{f} \in C^0_\delta$ we can define the function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{2 a}{\delta} (\delta/2 - x) & x \in [0,\delta/2] \\
\frac{2 \hat{f}(\delta)}{\delta} ( x - \delta/2) & x \in[\delta/2,\delta] \\
\hat{f}(x) & x \in[\delta , 1 - \delta] \\
\frac{\hat{f}(1-\delta) - b}{\delta} ( 1 - \delta - x) + \hat{f}(1-\delta) & x \in [1-\delta, 1] \end{cases}$$
Then by construction we have $f|_{[\delta,1-\delta]} = \hat{f}$, $f(0) = a$, $f(1) = b$, $f$ is continuous, and $f$ is a line between $a$ and $0$ on $[0,\delta/2]$. Hence, $f \in S^{a,b}$ and therefore $S^{a,b}_\delta = C^0_\delta$.

So, $S$ satisfies the extra constraint, but the function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}, x \mapsto 1 + x$ has always distance of at least $1$ from all functions in $S$, so $S$ is not be dense in $C^0$.